# Android : Facebook Logout

Tags: android, facebook, logout

I have a LoginViaFacebook Acitivity and a login button for facebook Login.I use the following code to login to facebook

```
private String[] permissions = {"publish_stream",
        "read_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins", "photo_upload",
        "email", "user_birthday" };

if (access_token != null) {
        Utility.fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
        token = access_token;

        Log.e("OnCretae Facebook Token------------", token);
    }
    if (expires != 0) {
        Utility.fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (CheckInternet.checkConn(LoginViaFacebook.this)) {

                Utility.fb.authorize(LoginViaFacebook.this, permissions,
                        new DialogListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "onFacebookError",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.e("Sajolllllllllllllllll", e + "");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "onError", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                                Log.e("Sajolllllllllllllllll", e + "");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                editor = sp.edit();
                                token = Utility.fb.getAccessToken();

                                Log.e("Token---------", token);
                                editor.putString("access_token",
                                        Utility.fb.getAccessToken());
                                editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                        Utility.fb.getAccessExpires());
                                editor.commit();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Login Successful",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(
                                        LoginViaFacebook.this, "",
                                        "Please Wait...", true);
                                Thread t = new Thread(retriveProfileData);
                                t.start();

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();

                            }
                        });
            }

        }
    });
```

I save the access token to login next time directly if user not logout

I have another activity namely Settings and have button Logout.I use following code to logout from facebook

```
lagoutLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final String[] items = new String[] { "Yes", "No" };
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SettingsActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    SettingsActivity.this);

            builder.setTitle("Select Option");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick

                            // from
                            // camera
                            if (item == 0) {

                                try {
                                    editor.remove("FacebookId");
                                    editor.remove("EmailId");
                                    editor.commit();

                                    Log.e("Pre----------------", sp1
                                            .getString("access_token", "d"));
                                    editor1.remove("access_token");
                                    editor1.remove("access_expires");
                                    editor1.commit();

                                    Log.e("After----------------", sp1
                                            .getString("access_token", "d"));

                                    Log.e("DATATTAT--------",
                                            sp.getString("FacebookId",
                                                    "saf")
                                                    + "  "
                                                    + sp.getString(
                                                            "EmailId", "as"));
                                    String r = Utility.fb
                                            .logout(SettingsActivity.this);
                                    Log.e("Res-----------", r);
                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            } else { // pick from file

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            dialog = builder.create();

            dialog.show();

        }

    });
```

The response from Facebook Logout method show true in Log.
But when i again run application it will automatically login to facebook
I can'nt find out the problem.Please help me

Comment: can you post the code for logout function in fb?

Comment: Fb logout code:::::: public String logout(Context context)
            throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        Util.clearCookies(context);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("method", "auth.expireSession");
        String response = request(b);
        setAccessToken(null);
        setAccessExpires(0);
        return response;
    }

Comment: i post my answer i got same logout function in my fb app.this code is worked for me. if you need that code use it. you have any queries ask me..

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and it worked fine

```
     public void logout() {
    if (!isConnected(activity)) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Internet not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    SessionEvents.onLogoutBegin();
    AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(this.facebook);
    asyncRunner.logout(this.context, new LogoutRequestListener());
}
```

And here is the listener

```
    public class LogoutRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {
    public void onComplete(String response, final Object state) {
        // callback should be run in the original thread, 
        // not the background thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                SessionEvents.onLogoutFinish();
                Intent intent= new Intent(activity,Login.class);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
                activity.finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For facebook sdk version 3 above

```
public void logoutFacebook() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session != null && session.isOpened()){
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are extending and using facebook openSession when logging you must close it using closeSession and put it in your logout or you can simply put it onDestroy just like this

```
public void onDestroy() {
        this.closeSession();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

I hope this will be help to you...

```
if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
    try {
        String str = mFacebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
        SessionStore.clear(getApplicationContext());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {                     
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing this answer from google suggestion and using facebook sdk v4 or above, just use this lines. It works perfectly.

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            }
```